# Improving scale out performance for multiple web instances using SignalR Redis Backplane

Tags: redis, signalr, signalr-backplane, scaleout-hserver

I have SignalR integrated in our application, and it has been working just fine.
Couple of days ago, due to some requirements, we had to support scale out of our application – and hence we opted for SignalR scale out using Redis.

However, since integration, the SignalR itself has stopped working, and the error we get is : NO TRANSPORT could be initialized successfully. try specifying a different transport or none at all for auto initialization.

Approaches applied : 
-   Tried with different versions of SignalR, as suggested online - Did not help
-   Increased connection timeout – Did not help

Need some help in resolving this. Suggestion on using any other approach is also welcome.

**[Update1] Adding code snippets**

```
public class Startup
{
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {
    // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis("server", port, "password", "AppName");
    app.MapSignalR();
  }
}
```

For more reference,  I followed this link  :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis

**[Update2]**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
 GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(110);
 GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
 GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
 GlobalHost.Configuration.TransportConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45);

 ConfigureAuth(app);
 ConfigureSignalR(app);

 // SignalR backplane code changes
 string server = RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable ?
                        RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(Constant.ConfigKeys.RedisCacheEndpoint) : 
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constant.ConfigKeys.RedisCacheEndpoint];
 string port = RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable ?
                      RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(Constant.ConfigKeys.RedisCachePort) :
                      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constant.ConfigKeys.RedisCachePort];
 string password = RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable ?
                          RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(Constant.ConfigKeys.RedisCachePassword) :
                          ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constant.ConfigKeys.RedisCachePassword];

 const string SIGNALR_REDIS_APPNAME = "Phoenix 2.0 Admin Tool";
 string connectionString = server + ":" + Int32.Parse(port) + ";password=" + password + ",ssl=True,abortConnect=False"; 
 RedisScaleoutConfiguration cfg = new RedisScaleoutConfiguration(connectionString, SIGNALR_REDIS_APPNAME);
 GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(cfg);
 app.MapSignalR();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the client code used to connect to SignalR? How did you scale out? Did you installed ARR in one IIS Server to configure a web farmer with the application servers?

Comment: @Alisson - Added code snippet inline in the question

Comment: **New findings** - It worked with on prem redis server, not with the Azure Redis cache. Assuming the problem might be in authentication. Any idea?

Comment: I have no clue. Did you have to change anything on prem server?

Comment: Nopes. Same old thing.

Answer (score 0):

We have an Azure AppService and are able to use SignalR w/ the Redis backplane.  I did observe that things did not work properly depending on the connection string content.  We used the `RedisScaleoutConfiguration` overload of the `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis` API instead of using the overload that you show.

Here is a block of code based on our working startup (values changed to protect the vulnerable):

```
const string SIGNALR_REDIS_APPNAME = "OurAppName";
string connectionString = "thename.redis.cache.windows.net:6380;password=somelongsecret,ssl=True,abortConnect=False";
RedisScaleoutConfiguration cfg = new RedisScaleoutConfiguration(connectionString, SIGNALR_REDIS_APPNAME);
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(cfg);
```

Obviously you can get an actual connection string from `web.config` with more code.  We also had trouble when specifying a non-default DB name so are using the default here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I may have missed something.  Are you running on-premise or in the cloud?  If cloud are you running in Azure AppService or CloudService?  If Azure App Service is WebSockets turned *on* in the Application Settings? Is Redis running locally or in the cloud?

Comment: The redis instance is on cloud, running on cloud service.
Websockets have been turned on as well.